# Disable customErrors only for a given Area in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, custom-errors

I have enabled `customErrors` in my `MVC5` web application as below.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Error/InternalServerError" mode="On">
  <error redirect="/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="/Error/InternalServerError" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
```

I have Area defined called "Admin" and I need to turn off `customErrors` for that particular Area.

I have tried adding web.config file with following code inside Areas folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But still my custom error is displaying, how can I disable `customErrors` only for a given Area in MVC5?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your customErrors in a location tag within your ***root*** web.config:

```
  <location path="areaName">
      <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
      </system.web>
  </location>
```